# Cheater vent from Behind Toilet

Tags: plumbing, toilet, vent

I would like to place a cheater vent (aav) behind the toilet. I just want to make sure this arrangement will work properly. Most of the vented toilet arrangements I see show the vent being downstream of the toilet. The Main toilet drain is actually 30 deg.[image] from the toilet to meet the main waste drain in that direction. Is this arrangement ok? Or should I wait till the toilet drain crosses under the adjacent wall and run the vent there. That would have the toilet working without a vent for about 4'.

[image]

I will have a box with a vent that is accessible from the wall inside the bathroom. The vent wont be enclosed with in the wall. I want to be able to perform maintenance on the valve if required. Sorry, I didn't draw that part of the system.

Answer (score 2):

AAV’s are legal in my location but they cannot be used inside walls. I usually put one in the sink cabinet as high up as I can get it that works fof the sink shower quite well and ok for the toilet.

Comment: If the AHJ will allow a vented chamber it should work fine.